# 'DirectoryObject' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayName'

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using the [Microsoft.Graph.Beta nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta). I was able to get the user and their manager using the following:

```
var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().Expand("Manager").GetAsync();
```

However, when I try to get the user's manager's name, I get an error:

```
var managerName = me.Manager.DisplayName;
```

> 'DirectoryObject' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayName' and no accessible extension method 'DisplayName' accepting a first argument of type 'DirectoryObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

The manager is of type `DirectoryObject` and I don't know how to get anything from it. It seems useless:

[image]

This shows the fields I can access. There's no `DisplayName` or anything. When I tried to debug it, I can see the manager's display name, but I can't get it programmatically:

[image]

Comment: *"When I tried to debug it, I can see the manager's display name, but I can't get it programmatically"* Where do you see this? You've zoomed in too close in your screenshot to see what this is a property of.

Comment: I was using VSCode's debugger. I don't know if zooming out helps (see left): https://i.imgur.com/6lQQNgZ.png.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your code to something like this..

```
string managerName = ((User)me.Manager).DisplayName;
```

Also, another way instead of using Expand like you've mentioned in question could be

```
 var manager = await graphServiceClient.Me.Manager.Request().GetAsync();
```

and then later to access display name..

```
 string managerName = ((User)manager).DisplayName;
```

Also, you mentioned that you're using Microsoft.Graph.Beta nuget package. At least user and manager related functionality should work properly even with stable version, i.e. Microsoft.Graph nuget package. May be you have some other reasons to use beta package in your case.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much. It was the casting that helped! I use expand because I don't want to make 2 network. requests. Thank you!